# What Minhag Is This Tefillin Wrapping?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Chacham [Ovadia Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadia_Yosef) is shown below wearing tefillin. I've never seen this style of tefillin wrapping. Is this of a particular group or minhag?

[image: side view of rabbi ovadia yosef wearing tefillin]
<sup>["Ovadia Yosef, 2007"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ovadia_Yosef,_2007.jpg) by [Talsardar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Talsardar) at the Hebrew Wikipedia, used with permission under [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

Comment: I've seen Temanim wear tefillin like this

Comment: I would be interested in seeing how he starts wrapping from the bayit of his shel yad.

Comment: @MenachemEliyahu - You can see a bit of how he does it in [this](http://www.eichlers.com//media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/0/100011-122.jpg) picture here. This was the only one I could find, though. It seems he has the minhag to cover the bayit of the shel yad with his sleeve.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi - It seems to me that this is more of a variation on the normal Sephardi wrap; Temanim wrap differently. Do you have a picture of a Temani wearing tefillin like this? That might help the OP a little.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you interested in the number of wraps around the arm, overlaps, or the hand? Sepharadim wrap eight times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wrapping is in accordance with the Yemenite(Teiman) custom.

Source: Nitei Gavriel Halachos V'Halichos Bar Mitzvah V'Hanachos Tefillin.

[image]